# URL Link to Calendar Month view from Existing View

Tags: uri, datetime

I have a page with some global header text. The page lists some events in a tabular format. I'd like to add a link (url) to my calendar within the text. I've tried to code a "<a href>" tag with what I thought was an appropriate url, but, I get the following:

> Warning: Creating default object from empty value in
>   calendar_plugin_row->pre_render() (line 312 of
>   /home3/hartfos4/public_html/mysitename/sites/all/modules/calendar/includes/calendar_plugin_row.inc).

followed by:

> 'calendar_plugin_style: A date argument is required when using the
>   calendar style, but it is missing or is not using the default date.'
>   in calendar_plugin_style->render() (line 238 of
>   /home3/hartfos4/public_html/mysitename/sites/all/modules/calendar/includes/calendar_plugin_style.inc).

Is there any way to compose a url to link to the calendar month?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this. I was trying to redirect to a second calendar from the global header text of another calendar.  I took a closer look at the second calendar and noticed that it did not have a default date in the **contextual filter**.  It may have gotten deleted after the fact.  I deleted the second calendar view and recreated it according to required specifications. I then edited the first calendar's global header text to use "<a href=>" and it successfully redirected to the second calendar.